# Is it possible to resize a partition in GUI mode in Fedora 17?

Tags: hard-drive, fedora

Is this possible to merge or resize a **partition** in **Fedora 17**, I have two different partitions in my Fedora OS(apart of OS) i need to merge that partitions. Is there any tool for that or any command's are there for that.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora should have a Gnome's partition editor installed by default. You will need to run it as root and you can only modify unmounted partitions. Open a terminal, switch to root and run `gparted`.

This won't work if you are trying to resize your `/` or `/home` partitions. For that, download a live session CD, boot into it and run `gparted` from there.